# What type of query to use and how - JOIN / UNION

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm pretty new to ruby and have tried hunting about for this but no solutions work to what I'm after.

I have an association of Companies to Jobs. So one Company has many jobs and each job belongs to a Company.

After searching for a Job - I want to query the associated Company ID that is saved to each Job.

So after searching for a Job title for example "Ruby" - I want to return all Jobs that match that title and their associated Company data. The below query kind of works the only problem is that the Jobs ID is replaced with the Company ID and I can never access each Jobs ID

```
@jobs_list = Jobs.select("jobs.*, companies.*").where("title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:jobs][:title]}%").joins("LEFT JOIN companies on jobs.company_id = companies.id")
```

Any suggestions / better practises?

Comment: Well it is certainly a very poor practice to use select* in any code on production.

Comment: I just wanted results - this isn't a production

Answer (score 2):

Firstly make sure your `Job` model has a line: `belongs_to :company`

Then use `includes` to eager load the company data:

```
@jobs = Jobs.where("title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:jobs][:title]}%").
             includes(:company)
```

You can now access the company data like this without any further database queries:

```
@jobs.each do |job|
  job_name = job.name
  company_name = job.company.name
end
```

Comment: Just to add to that, I've found the "bullet" gem to be excellent for identifying situations where eager loading could be beneficial.